# Is there a Python library for service discovery using SSDP or UPnP?

Tags: python, upnp, service-discovery

Is there a library for implementing Simple Service Discovery Protocol(SSDP) via UPnP in Python? Basically, I want to make protocols for SSDP using python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://brisa.garage.maemo.org/doc/html/upnp/ssdp.html

Comment: python-brisa - the methods given at the end of the page provided by your link can be used in python environment?? like , I am using eclipse for python code

Comment: I have python 2.7 installed on my pc. Which One I should download?There is no option for it

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Coherence - what is the difference between this link and your link? are they both good?